# Update CRM from Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, crm

I'm building a website for a client, he wants to update his stock from his Presta website to his CRM. In order to achieve that it's very simple, I only have to call an URL like this :

`http://crm.com/client1/bin/majstock.php?mode=stock&pdt=REF~-1;REF2~-1`

Where REF is obviously the Ref of the product, and the number after ~ is the quantity to update, so in this example the customer bought 2 products, one is REF and the other one is REF2.

The problem is that I don't know where I should call this URL, and where I can get the parameters

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the hook `actionOrderStatusUpdates` like that:

```
public function hookActionOrderStatusUpdate($params)
{
    $OrderState = $params['newOrderStatus']; // an OrderState object
    // $OrderState->id // order status ID

    // $params['id_order'] // order ID
    $Order = new Order((int)$params['id_order']);
    $products = $Order->getProductsDetail();
    // or
    $products = $Order->getProducts();
}
```

Comment: Great , how can I get the ref of articles with the id ? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Can you explain what do you call "ref of articles" and what ID do you have in mind?

Comment: The references of the products, The order ID

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new module with a hook on `actionOrderStatusUpdate` and call the CRM when the desired status is set on the order.

Comment: Can you elaborate please ? I'm really new to prestashop, I know how to create a module, and how I can hook on actionorderStatusUpdate, but how can I check the status ? Thanks